# Assign a class with link_to_unless_current based on a condition with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to use link_to_unless_current to assign a class based on a condition. I have tried this:

```
<li >
<%= link_to_unless_current subject.name, :controller => "public", :action => subject.permalink, :class => "drop" if subject.pages.visible.size > 1  %>
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: keep in `()` like `class: ("drop" if subject.pages.visible.size > 1)`

Comment: SyntaxError : 
C:/wamp/www/RiverParkCarWash/app/views/public/_navigation.html.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting => ...n => subject.permalink, :class: ("drop" if subject.pages.vi... ... ^ C:/wamp/www/RiverParkCarWash/app/views/public/_navigation.html.erb:9: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting keyword_end '.freeze; subject.pages.visible.sorted.each do |page| ^ C:/wamp/www/RiverParkCarWash/app/views/public/_navigation.html.erb:23: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input

Comment: <ul id="menu" class="noprint">
  <% subjects.visible.each do |subject| %>
     
<li >
<%= link_to_unless_current subject.name, :controller => "public", :action => subject.permalink, :class:  ("drop" if subject.pages.visible.size > 1)  %>
<ul>
<% subject.pages.visible.sorted.each do |page| %>
<li>
<%= link_to_unless_current(page.name, {:action => page.permalink}) %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</li><% end %>
      
</ul>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
<%= link_to_unless_current subject.name,
      { controller: 'public', action: subject.permalink },
      class: ("drop" if subject.pages.visible.size > 1)  %>
```

Btw, notation `:symbol =>` can be replaced with `symbol:` since Ruby 1.9. It's much easier to read and faster to type.

Comment: Thank You, Works Great!!

Comment: Hi Dimakura!, sorry for the late reply. I'm getting an output like this: <a href="/?class=drop">Subject  Name</a>
any idea how to get the class to be outside the href?

Comment: @JorgeVillatoro sorry, `:action` and `:controller` need to be grouped together (see updated answer)